# Hadoop - copyFromLocal inner workflow?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When we give commands like `copyFromLocal` or put to copy data from client to HDFS, How this process actually works?

I read in HDFS Architecture that, a client will contact to Namenode to get datanode list and then make connection and transfer the data.

Is there any other way or any way to make it faster?

Which classes are invoking this behavior such as checking datanode list etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can start browsing through the code at the method  `copyFromLocal` in the class

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
```

For easiness, I am quoting the [url](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java#FsShell.copyFromLocal%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%5B%5D,java.lang.String%29)